# Is there a way to pass on an async function as a parameter to another async function

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, caching, lambda, async-await

I made this function

```
Public Shared Async Function downloadStringAndCacheAsync(fileName As String, MaxtimeElapsedInSeconds As Long, GetResultFromSomeOperation As Func(Of Task(Of String))) As Task(Of String)
    Dim fileDate = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName)
    Dim timeElapsedInSeconds = (Now - fileDate).TotalSeconds
    Dim cachedVersion = ""
    If timeElapsedInSeconds > MaxtimeElapsedInSeconds Then
        Dim resultTask = GetResultFromSomeOperation() ' so function1() return Task(Of String)
        Dim result = Await resultTask
        TexttoFile(result, fileName, False)
        cachedVersion = result
    Else
        cachedVersion = fileToText(fileName)
    End If

    Return cachedVersion
End Function
```

That function has one purpose. Say I download certain data, like currency price data from the web. Say I want to do so only every 18 hours. So if 18 hours hasn't passed, I just want to use old data.

Simple.

I implement this using simple text file.

Now I want the function to take another function as parameter. The other function return Task(of String) as a return value.

Basically we get the task from that function.

Then we "await" the task.

Pretty simple stuffs right?

Then I tried to call this

```
        Dim str1 = Await CookieAwareWebClient.downloadStringAndCacheAsync _
            ("First5000Coins", 3600,
              Function()
                  CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async(url, "", {"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0", "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"})
              End Function)
```

I got a warning

The warning said

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning BC42358 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the Await operator to the result of the call.   nicehash2
```

I am confused

CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async

should not have been awaited at that function.

It should quickly provide Task(of String). And then the function that call it will await the Task.

Why do I get the warning?

And is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding return on function call works.

So

```
        Dim result1 = Await CookieAwareWebClient.downloadStringAndCacheAsync _
            ("Currencydata.txt", 64800, Function()
                                            Return CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async(url, "", {Tuple.Create("apikey", "UqG3P4SSrIRyU4R9CPjZsizXbz70Yh7H")})
                                        End Function)
```

would work.

It seems that multi line Lambda Function doesn't automatically return value without explicit keyword Return.

If I keep all in a single line then I may not need return keyword.

So this was a simple bug.